# node.js when different users make request at the same time returns the same response

Tags: node.js, request

I have node.js web app with such code

```
import request from 'request';

export const promisedRequest = (options: any): any => {
    const deferred = new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
        return request(options, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
            if (error || !(response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 208)) {
                reject({ error: error || response });
            } else {
                resolve({ response, body });
            }
        });
    });
    return deferred;
};
```

and it calls in this way

```
export const getProduct = (token: string, barcode: string): Promise<any> =>
    promisedRequest({
        url: `${process.env.API_URL}`,
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'X-Token': token,
        },
        body: {
            barcode: barcode,
        },
    })
        .then(({ body }: any) => body.data[0])
        .catch((error: any): void => {
            const errorMessage = `Cannot get product: Product barcode: ${barcode}`;
            console.error(errorMessage, error);
            throw Error(errorMessage);
        });
```

I checked the browser and requests send right but if I make requests almost at the same time (~2 milliseconds) I get the same response for two users.
Please help me with this. Thank you very much.